# How to circle text in paragraph that points to other text to work in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, tikz-styles

I would like to know how to go about circling words in a paragraph and then have arrows pointing from the circled words to other words, like this:

[image]

This is just the start of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}


This is just some \tcbox[enhanced,colback=green!25]{text that} I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems that you may search for `tikzmark` here. You should find what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with `tikzmarknode` from the `tikzmark` library.
You can define more styles and option but you get the idea.
Note that you may need at least two compilations to get the right position of nodes.

[image: Tikzmark to comment a text]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={inner sep=2pt,fill=cyan!50,draw=blue,line width=1pt,rounded corners}}

This is just some \tikzmarknode[mynode]{A}{text that} I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[->,line width=1pt,blue] (A) --++ (1,1) node[above right] {your comment here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colors as you want them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base, top=0.2pt,bottom=0.2pt,left=0.1pt,right=0.1pt,before upper=\strut,#1}
\begin{document}
This is just some \mybox{is} \mybox{another}.

This is just some \mybox[enhanced,colback=green!25]{text that} I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again. This is just some text that I will repeat for this section again and again.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you didn't read the question correctly. OP wants those  `tcbox`es to point to other places with arrows.